# Where to edit grails startup command line in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

Grails-2.5.0 startup fails if fork mode is disabled.

I've found a workaround at https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-12129, which says;

> Don't use the spring loaded java agent. Removing the following from the command started by IntelliJ is enough

But I cannot find where the command is written.

Run -> Edit Configurations doesn't have any option to disable agent.

Where should I edit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open the run configuration you should see fields like `Module`, `Command Line`, `VM options` and more. So add this to the `Command Line` field

```
-noreloading -Ddisable.auto.recompile=true run-app
```

That should stop Grails from reloading your application.

Comment: I've found another workaround. Using JRebel and its IntelliJ IDEA plugin replaces default spring-loaded-agent. JRebel agent works like a charm.